# Angular Environment file not seen in the distribution folder

Tags: angular, environment

I have an angular 8 application and testing the timeout set in the enviornment.ts file. I have currently set the timeout to 6 minutes
I have two enviornment files that is enviornment.ts and enviornment.prod.ts. I believe that enviornment.prod.ts is used when the 
ng build --prod is executed.

After running  the ng build command , I am unable to locate the enviornment file in the distribution folder.Could somebody tell me
where can i find it. Is it in some binary etc

This is what my environment file looks like

```
// The file contents for the current environment will overwrite these during build.
// The build system defaults to the dev environment which uses `environment.ts`, but if you do
// `ng build --env=prod` then `environment.prod.ts` will be used instead.
// The list of which env maps to which file can be found in `.angular-cli.json`.

export const environment = {
    production: false,
    baseUrl: "http://localhost:57973",
    loginUrl: "/Login",
    adminUrl: "/Admin",
    userIdleMinutes: 10
};
```

Comment: I didnt downvote you, but i dont understand you, do you get an error? when you do a production build all.ts files are bundled into js... you will never see the env.ts file, or any .ts file.... can you give more information? :)

Comment: in dist folder only .js files are present, you cannot expect a .ts file there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you need to actually use your `environment.ts` file in your code. For example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { environment } from '../environments/environment';

@Component({})
export class AppComponent {
  env = environment;
  constructor() {
    console.log(this.env.baseUrl);
  }
}
```

Otherwise, unused code will be tree-shaked.

Then, your code from the `environment.ts` file will be bundled to the main-XXXXX.js file.

Answer (score 1):

There are two key files for all things environment.

---

*angular.json* - which should have something like the following:

```
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
```

In other words if the configuration is production any reference to environment.ts will be overwritten and environment.prod.ts will be used instead.

**So yes, you are correct** ...*I believe that enviornment.prod.ts is used when the ng build --prod is executed.*

---

*main.ts* - which should have

```
if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode()
}
```

This removes development checks in change detection for example.
You'll see console message `Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.` if `enableProdMode()` has not been run.

---

Answer (score 1):

`environment.ts` is used while developing.
the content of its variables, is replaced **when compiling**.

that said, the whole concept of an environment file the way angular team implemented it  has major flaws in its basics. biggest one, in my opinion, is the need to **compile per environment**. in practice, having different compiled files for testing and different ones for production is a BAD IDEA.

you should deploy exactly, not similar, but exactly, what you test.

davembush [suggested a workaround](https://medium.com/@davembush/where-to-store-angular-configurations-c5d5bb348743) using a config file, or so, similar to .net's web.config  that fills in your configs on the fly. this requires a bit of hack&slash, but gets you a compile-once-deploy-wherever app.

worth noting.